# Extract value that match a string out of range of columns in R

Tags: r, search

Write the relevant code in R. I have a dataframe (called realData) that have 10 variables named "RealAttribute_X" where X is a number between 1 to 10 (including).
Each column contains one of ten attributes: "intelligence", "attractiveness", "charisma", "ambition", "laziness", "generosity", "joyfulness", "friendliness", "arrogance", "calmness". The attributes are randomly assigned to 1 of the 10 "RealAttribute_X".

```
dt<-structure(list(session_id = c("17472631", "17472632", "17472633", 
"17472635", "17472636", "17472638"), RealAttribute_1 = c("Moderately ugly", 
"Very dull", "Very distant", "Very joyful", "Moderately joyful", 
"Very distant"), RealAttribute_2 = c("Very nervous", "Very gloomy", 
"Very generous", "Moderately charismatic", "Moderately hard working", 
"Moderately modest"), RealAttribute_3 = c("Slightly generous", 
"Moderately ugly", "Moderately arrogant", "Moderately calm", 
"Moderately charismatic", "Moderately charismatic"), RealAttribute_4 = c("Moderately arrogant", 
"Slightly generous", "Very dull", "Moderately distant", "Slightly distant", 
"Slightly ambitious"), RealAttribute_5 = c("Slightly unambitious", 
"Moderately calm", "Moderately unambitious", "Moderately lazy", 
"Very modest", "Moderately intelligent"), RealAttribute_6 = c("Slightly dull", 
"Slightly ambitious", "Very calm", "Moderately ambitious", "Moderately generous", 
"Moderately generous"), RealAttribute_7 = c("Very intelligent", 
"Slightly distant", "Very intelligent", "Slightly ugly", "Very good-looking", 
"Very lazy"), RealAttribute_8 = c("Very joyful", "Slightly modest", 
"Slightly joyful", "Very arrogant", "Very ambitious", "Slightly good-looking"
), RealAttribute_9 = c("Very distant", "Very lazy", "Slightly good-looking", 
"Very generous", "Moderately intelligent", "Moderately gloomy"
), RealAttribute_10 = c("Slightly lazy", "Moderately intelligent", 
"Slightly hard working", "Moderately intelligent", "Very calm", 
"Moderately nervous")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

head(dt)
```

Each attribute can have one of six values. The Attributes and their optional values are: intelligence = "Very unintelligent", "Moderately unintelligent", "Slightly unintelligent", "Slightly intelligent", "Moderately intelligent", "Very intelligent"
attractiveness = "Very ugly", "Moderately ugly", "Slightly ugly", "Slightly good-looking", "Moderately good-looking", "Very good-looking"
laziness = "Very lazy", "Moderately lazy", "Slightly lazy", "Slightly hard working", "Moderately hard working", "Very hard working"
friendliness = "Very distant", "Moderately distant", "Slightly distant", "Slightly friendly", "Moderately friendly", "Very friendly"
charisma = "Very dull", "Moderately dull", "Slightly dull", "Slightly charismatic", "Moderately charismatic", "Very charismatic"
calmness = "Very nervous", "Moderately nervous", "Slightly nervous", "Slightly calm", "Moderately calm", "Very calm"
generosity = "Very stingy", "Moderately stingy", "Slightly stingy", "Slightly generous", "Moderately generous", "Very generous"
joyfullness = "Very gloomy", "Moderately gloomy", "Slightly gloomy", "Slightly joyful", "Moderately joyful", "Very joyful"
arrogance = "Very arrogant", "Moderately arrogant", "Slightly arrogant", "Slightly modest", "Moderately modest", "Very modest"
ambition = "Very unambitious", "Moderately unambitious", "Slightly unambitious", "Slightly ambitious", "Moderately ambitious", "Very ambitious"

I'm trying to write a code in R that would create 10 new columns, one for each of the attributes ("intelligence", "attractiveness", "charisma", "ambition", "laziness", "generosity", "joyfulness", "friendliness", "arrogance", "calmness"), find the right variable in the existing dataframe that contain the relevant attribute and will allocate the value of that attribute to the correct new variable.

For example, this is the first four rows of the dataframe:
RealAttribute_1: "Moderately ugly", "Very dull", "Very distant", "Very joyful"<br
RealAttribute_2: "Very nervous", "Very gloomy", "Very generous", "Moderately charismatic"<br
RealAttribute_3: "Slightly generous", "Moderately ugly", "Moderately arrogant", "Moderately calm"<br
RealAttribute_4: "Moderately arrogant", "Slightly generous", "Very dull", "Moderately distant"<br
RealAttribute_5: "Slightly unambitious", "Moderately calm", "Moderately unambitious", "Moderately lazy"<br
RealAttribute_6: "Slightly dull", "Slightly ambitious", "Very calm", "Moderately ambitious"<br
RealAttribute_7: "Very intelligent", "Slightly distant", "Very intelligent", "Slightly ugly"<br
RealAttribute_8: "Very joyful", "Slightly modest", "Slightly joyful", "Very arrogant"<br
RealAttribute_9 "Very distant", "Very lazy", "Slightly good-looking", "Very generous"<br
RealAttribute_10: "Slightly lazy", "Moderately intelligent", "Slightly hard working", "Moderately intelligent"<br

So the end result for the first four rows should look like this:
intelligence: "Very intelligent", "Moderately intelligent", "Very intelligent", "Moderately intelligent"<br
attractiveness: " Moderately ugly", "Moderately ugly", "Slightly good-looking", "Slightly ugly"<br
laziness: "Slightly lazy", "Very lazy", "Slightly hard working", "Moderately lazy"<br
friendliness: "Very distant", "Slightly distant", "Very distant", "Moderately distant"<br
charisma: "Slightly dull", "Very dull", "Very dull", "Moderately charismatic"<br
calmness: "Very nervous", "Moderately calm", "Very calm", "Moderately calm"<br
generosity: "Slightly generous", "Slightly generous", "Very generous", "Very generous"<br
joyfullness: "Very joyful", "Very gloomy", "Slightly joyful", "Very joyful"<br
arrogance: "Moderately arrogant", "Slightly modest", "Moderately arrogant", "Very arrogant"<br
ambition: "Slightly unambitious", "Slightly ambitious", "Moderately unambitious", "Moderately ambitious"<br

I defined all attributes values

```
attribute_values <- list(
  intelligence = c("Very unintelligent", "Moderately unintelligent", "Slightly unintelligent", 
                   "Slightly intelligent", "Moderately intelligent", "Very intelligent"),
  attractiveness = c("Very ugly", "Moderately ugly", "Slightly ugly", 
                     "Slightly good-looking", "Moderately good-looking", "Very good-looking"),
  laziness = c("Very lazy", "Moderately lazy", "Slightly lazy", 
               "Slightly hard working", "Moderately hard working", "Very hard working"),
  friendliness = c("Very distant", "Moderately distant", "Slightly distant", 
                   "Slightly friendly", "Moderately friendly", "Very friendly"),
  charisma = c("Very dull", "Moderately dull", "Slightly dull", 
               "Slightly charismatic", "Moderately charismatic", "Very charismatic"),
  calmness = c("Very nervous", "Moderately nervous", "Slightly nervous", 
               "Slightly calm", "Moderately calm", "Very calm"),
  generosity = c("Very stingy", "Moderately stingy", "Slightly stingy", 
                 "Slightly generous", "Moderately generous", "Very generous"),
  joyfullness = c("Very gloomy", "Moderately gloomy", "Slightly gloomy", 
                  "Slightly joyful", "Moderately joyful", "Very joyful"),
  arrogance = c("Very arrogant", "Moderately arrogant", "Slightly arrogant", 
                "Slightly modest", "Moderately modest", "Very modest"),
  ambition = c("Very unambitious", "Moderately unambitious", "Slightly unambitious", 
               "Slightly ambitious", "Moderately ambitious", "Very ambitious")
)
```

But started checking my code for the first variable (intelligence):

```
intelligence_values <- c("Very unintelligent", "Moderately unintelligent", "Slightly unintelligent", 
                         "Slightly intelligent", "Moderately intelligent", "Very intelligent")

realData$Intelligence <- apply(dt[, grep("RealAttribute_", colnames(realData), value = TRUE)], 1, function(row) {
  match_value <- which(row %in% intelligence_values)[1]
  if (is.na(match_value)) {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(intelligence_values[match_value])
  }
})
```

This code returned only NAs to the "intelligence" column.
I also tried:

```
realData <- realData %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Intelligence = intelligence_values[match(c_across(starts_with("RealAttribute")), intelligence_values)])
```

But got the following error:
Error in `c_across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.

And after running rlang::last_trace():
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `c_across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and `group_by()`.
**---
Backtrace:
x

1. +-realData %>% rowwise() %>% ...
2. -plyr::mutate(...)
3. -base::eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())
4. ```
   \-base::eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())
   ```
5. ```
     +-base::match(c_across(starts_with("RealAttribute")), intelligence_values)
   ```
6. ```
     \-dplyr::c_across(starts_with("RealAttribute"))
   ```

Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 4 hidden frames.

Any ideas what went wrong or how should I write it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another thing to watch out for in your code is that you seem to have both plyr and dplyr loaded. These two packages have some function names on common, like mutate and summarize, which can cause problems since they work differently (eg plyr::mutate does not see groups created with group_by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simpler to do by making a table connecting the attributes we might encounter (it looks like 1 or 2 per category) with their respective category. Then we can reshape the data long, extract the attribute, join it to the lookup table, and use that to define which column the entry should be placed in.

```
library(tidyverse)

attribute_table <- data.frame(
  attribute = c("ugly", "nervous", "generous", "arrogant", "unambitious", "dull", 
                "intelligent", "joyful", "distant", "lazy", "gloomy", "calm", 
                "ambitious", "modest", "good-looking", "hard working", "charismatic"),
  category = c("attractiveness", "calmness", "generosity", "arrogance", "ambition", "charisma",
               "intelligence", "joyfulness", "friendliness", "laziness", "joyfulness", "calmness",
               "ambition", "arrogance", "attractiveness", "laziness", "charisma")
)

dt |>
  pivot_longer(-session_id) |>
  separate(value, c("degree", "attribute"), sep = " ", extra = "merge", remove = FALSE) |>
  left_join(attribute_table) |>
  select(session_id, value, category) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = value)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  session_id attractiveness        calmness           generosity          arrogance           ambition             charisma intelligence joyfulness friendliness laziness
  <chr>      <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>               <chr>               <chr>                <chr>    <chr>        <chr>      <chr>        <chr>   
1 17472631   Moderately ugly       Very nervous       Slightly generous   Moderately arrogant Slightly unambitious Slightl… Very intell… Very joyf… Very distant Slightl…
2 17472632   Moderately ugly       Moderately calm    Slightly generous   Slightly modest     Slightly ambitious   Very du… Moderately … Very gloo… Slightly di… Very la…
3 17472633   Slightly good-looking Very calm          Very generous       Moderately arrogant Moderately unambiti… Very du… Very intell… Slightly … Very distant Slightl…
4 17472635   Slightly ugly         Moderately calm    Very generous       Very arrogant       Moderately ambitious Moderat… Moderately … Very joyf… Moderately … Moderat…
5 17472636   Very good-looking     Very calm          Moderately generous Very modest         Very ambitious       Moderat… Moderately … Moderatel… Slightly di… Moderat…
6 17472638   Slightly good-looking Moderately nervous Moderately generous Moderately modest   Slightly ambitious   Moderat… Moderately … Moderatel… Very distant Very la…
```